# Regex matches new lines contains text after line contains only specific characters

Tags: php, regex

I have a text for a book pages that may have footnotes at the end of the string like the following example:

```
والخاتِم بكسر التاء اسم فاعل، فكأنه قد جاء آخر الرسل، والخاتَم بفتح التاء اسم آلة، كأنه قد ختمت به الرسالة.
__________

(1) - سورة الأحزاب آية : 43.
(2) - سورة البقرة آية : 157.
(3) - سورة الأنعام آية : 17.
(4) - سورة الكهف آية : 19.
```

The line that I mean in the sample and the specific characters in this case are [Kashidas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashida) `_` (It is not dash `-`), in Latin, it called underscore. What I need to get is matching the four lines or any number of lines under that line.

What I have tried let only to match the first line under that line:`/_.*\n*(.*)/gum` and this is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oV9xA0/1). The only way to get them all, is to repeat the pattern portion `\n*(.*)` n times equals to the number of lines in the footnotes i.e four times, regarding the example case, and this is not a practical solution like [**this demo**](https://regex101.com/r/oV9xA0/2)

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/oV9xA0/3)? Results are in capturing group `2`

Comment: Unfortunately no, I need the lines after the Kashida line, exactly as the second demo that I have regarded in the question but without need to repeat  `\n*(.*)` specific times equals to the lines number. @hek2mgl

Comment: Are you trying to separate the footnotes from the text associated with them.. and the footnotes are always under +4 underscores?

Comment: No, it is just lines with its text what ever is.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the `\G` anchor here:

```
preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!^)|_)\R+\K[^\n]+~', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/376360)

Comment: I don't need the four lines as one match. Indeed, I need them as four mtaches, each one is a line of them like the [second demo](https://regex101.com/r/oV9xA0/2) that I have shown in the question but without the need to repeat `\n*(.*)` specific -*in our case four*- times.

Answer (score 0):

Basically its not that easy to catch lines, and then every match. But what can you do is to catch everything after line, and then match again every line.

You can do that making:

```
 /_{4,}.+/gums
 /(\(.*?\.)*/gums
```

I hope that is good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this successfully:

```
$text = "_________\r\n\r\nLine 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\r\n";
$matches = array();
$pattern = '/_+\r\n\r\n(.+)/s'; // s to have . match newlines.
                                // Change \r\n to \n if appropriate

// Extract all footnotes
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
$footnotes = $matches[1]; // $matches[0] is the whole matched string,
                          // $matches[1] is the part within ()
$matches = array();
$pattern = '/(.+)/'; // Don't match newlines here

// Extract individual footnotes
preg_match_all($pattern, $footnotes, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) { // preg_match_all returns multi-dimensional array
    // Do something with each footnote
}
```